# How to restrict object creation only through parent class object?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

Consider the following example.

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Child createChild();

// some member data and functions can go here.
}

class Child: public Parent
{
// some member data and functions can go here.
}
```

I would like to allow creation of "Child" class only through the method provided in the Parent class. That is I would like to deny the options to the user to instantiate an object of the Child class. I would also like avoid all the other default constructions of the Child class.
How is it possible?

```
Parent p;
Child c = p.createChild(); // should be possible
Child d; //should not be allowed
Child e = c; // may  be allowed
```

Comment: Impossible. There's no way `Child c = p.createChild();` can be allowed to work while `Child e = c;` may not. Your demands don't make much sense to me. (Unless you intend to make your classes move-only, and `Child e = std::move(c);` may work, is that the case?)

Comment: @StoryTeller wouldn't c++17 guaranteed copy elision remove the need for the copy/move constructors?

Comment: @Mgetz - Indeed. But this was tagged c++11. If it's a mistagging my comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You are right, it may be impossible if we don't allow Child e=c. So editing my question.

Comment: @StoryTeller actually I think it's incredibly relevant as that's a major change in behavior as far as the answer is concerned. Since this is possible in c++17 without quirks and impossible in C++11 without making the object movable or copyable.

Comment: @Mgetz • even with copy elision, aren't they required to be available and accessible?  Or did that get changed with C++17's guaranteed copy elision optimization as well?

Comment: @Eljay AFAIK (and I'm by no means a committee authority) you can `delete` both the copy and move constructors and it should work either way [it compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/muynDh)

Answer (score 6):

You can make the `Child` constructor `private`, and have `Parent::createChild` be a `friend` of `Child`.

---

Do note [the comment by StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021242/how-to-restrict-object-creation-only-through-parent-class-object#comment87058386_50021242), in that your copy-constructor still needs to be public.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
class Parent
{
public:
      static Parent* InstantiateParent(); // for completeness' sake
      static Child* InstantiateChild();
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    Child();
    Child(Child& other):
    Child& operator = (Child& other);

    friend class Parent;
public:
};

/* impl.cpp */

#include "header.hpp";

Child* Parent::InstantiateChild()
{
    return new Child;
}

Parent* Parent::InstantiateParent()
{
    return new Parent;
}
```

Although, separating creation from the target class through some variation of factory pattern has its own advantages.

Answer (score 0):

You could have CreateChild() return something other than a Child, which is publicly move-constructable to a Child. You pay for the move, because it isn't copy elided, and the code is redundant come c++17.

Could you live with taking a const or right reference to the temporary, which will extend its lifetime? I don't think there are any cases where it wouldn't have the same lifetime as the uncopyable object created directly.